# How to convert varchar to numeric to use in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have this table that is storing information of employee. The datatype of Id is bigint. Now in code when developer is sending me IDs to extract data against, he's sending me in string format as apparently he cannot pass this `453, 454` into integer field. Is there anyway to convert this into bigint so I could use this into IN operator.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(25) = '453, 454'
SELECT FirstName+' '+LastName Employee FROM Employee WHERE ID IN (CAST(@string AS BIGINT))
```

When I run this query I'm getting following error. Hope someone could help.

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

Comment: You are trying to cast '453, 454' into an INT. Try to split them before casting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should seriously *avoid* storing CSV data in your SQL tables, because it represents unnormalized data.  That being said, there is a way we can write your query even with CSV data, using a slight correction to the data in `@string`:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(25) = '453,454';

SELECT
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName Employee
FROM Employee
WHERE ',' + @string + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(10), ID) + ',%';
```

### Demo

The trick here is to convert your input CSV `453,454` into this:

```
,453,454,
```

Then, we simply search for `%,ID,%` in that modified CSV string.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DECLARE @string varchar(25) = '453, 454';

SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Employee 
FROM Employee AS E
JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@string, ',') AS S
    ON S.value = E.ID
```

Demo here : [(thanks to Tim Biegeleisen)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7241c0cc1e14813d6ac5ad2cc284c57)

Comment: I like this answer +1, and it's a good example of where the lack of order in the output from `STRING_SPLIT` does not matter.  Note that this would only run on more recent versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested my following query in db2 it worked for me. 
ORDEREXECUTED column originally having type INTEGER I am able to put in where clause:
It worked for me :

```
SELECT ORDEREXECUTED, CAST(ORDEREXECUTED AS INTEGER), CAST(ORDEREXECUTED AS VARCHAR) FROM DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE CAST(ORDEREXECUTED AS VARCHAR)='2';
```

Please refer below screen shot : 
[image: ORDEREXECUTED column having type INTEGER type]

Output for the above query :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

String_Split from SS 2016 worked.

```
DECLARE #TEMPTABLE (id INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE 
SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT('10,'20','30',',')

SELECT NUMERIC_FIELD FROM TABLE
WHERE 
NUMERIC_FIELD IN (SELECT id FROM #TEMPTABLE)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).